# Read from File ASCII art Replace, Write to File

Tags: java

Trying to read text from ASCII art text file (it contains a series of blank spaces and '*' characters).  Then, I want to be able to change the asterisks to whatever character the user wishes.

I also want to select a random file. All three files exist.  I can store them as a list, if needed.

When executed, this code prompts user for substitution text but then just returns the file read location (including the random number 1-3).

```
import java.util.Scanner;
import java.util.Random;
import java.io.*;

public class AsciiArt
 {
  public static void main(String[]args) throws IOException
   {
    System.out.println("ASCII Art\n");
    Scanner kbd = new Scanner(System.in);
    Random randomGen = new Random();
    int verSub = randomGen.nextInt(3)+1;

    String fullSub = "/user/****/data/****"+verSub+".dat";
    File inputFile = new File(fullSub);
    System.out.print("Enter substitution text? ");
    String subText = kbd.next();
    Scanner input = new Scanner(fullSub);
    PrintWriter outputFile = new PrintWriter("newFile.txt")
    String line;
    while(input.hasNext()){
        line = input.nextLine();
        int i, subIdx = 0;
        for (i = 0;  i < line.length(); i++){
         if(line.charAt(i) == '*'){
          outputFile.print(subText.charAt(subIdx));
          ++subIdx;
          }
         if(subIdx == subText.length()){
          subIdx = 0;
          }
         else{
          outputFile.print(line.charAt(i));
          }
        } 
        } 
    input.close();
    outputFile.close();
    System.out.println();

   }
 }
```

Comment: what exactly is the problem?

Comment: All that is returned is the file read location. No file is written to and nothing else is returned in the terminal.

Comment: The new file is created in the same directory as the program. If you are running inside IDE, it might be inside `bin`. Try giving full path.